# Is it possible to declare a query with another table JOIN in room database

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sqlite, android-room, procedure

I have a complex query and I want to use procedure in my android Room database queries. Is it possible with the android Room database?

Example in sql:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE procedure_name
AS
sql_statement
GO;
```

```kotlin
@Query(SELECT * FROM PROCEDURE p LEFT JOIN OTHER_TABLE ot on p.id = ot.id)
fun getMyData(): LiveData<List<ResultModel>>
```

I want to define the following query as a view Ideally where :myId is variable:

```sql
SELECT j.* FROM ChatItemView j 
  INNER JOIN (SELECT groupId, 
  CASE 
    WHEN (senderId = :myId) THEN receiverId 
    WHEN (senderId != :myId) THEN senderId 
  END as chat_item_id, 
  MAX(messageTime) as max_sent_time 
  FROM ViewChatItem j 
  GROUP BY j.groupId, CASE 
  WHEN j.groupId=0 THEN chat_item_id END) j_max 
ON (((CASE 
        WHEN j.senderId = :myId THEN j.receiverId = chat_item_id 
        WHEN j.senderId != :myId THEN j_max.chat_item_id END) 
   AND j.groupId = 0) OR (j.groupId = j_max.groupId)) 
   AND j.messageTime = j_max.max_sent_time 
ORDER BY messageTime DESC
```

Comment: Which database do you use? Is it SQLite?

Comment: @forpas this is right android `Room` library is based on SQLite database

Comment: There are no procedures in SQLite. You can create Views.

Comment: @forpas I actually need to pass some parameters to the procedure query, I am unable to pass parameters to views. I can write one big query but its hard to wrap my head around that. I want to break it down and views aren't helping me with that as I need to pass variables.

Comment: You can pass parameters to views in the WHERE clauses of SELECT statements. You must post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Comment: @forpas Please check now. I have added the query I want to convert to a view. I want :myId as a variable.

Comment: Even if its not possible with a view, any other way is also fine when I can take this complex query and do a join with another query I want for unread message count.

Answer (score 0):

does this work for you?

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM (SELECT j.* FROM ChatItemView j 
  INNER JOIN (SELECT groupId, 
  CASE 
    WHEN (senderId = :myId) THEN receiverId 
    WHEN (senderId != :myId) THEN senderId 
  END as chat_item_id, 
  MAX(messageTime) as max_sent_time 
  FROM ViewChatItem j 
  GROUP BY j.groupId, CASE 
  WHEN j.groupId=0 THEN chat_item_id END) j_max 
ON (((CASE 
        WHEN j.senderId = :myId THEN j.receiverId = chat_item_id 
        WHEN j.senderId != :myId THEN j_max.chat_item_id END) 
   AND j.groupId = 0) OR (j.groupId = j_max.groupId)) 
   AND j.messageTime = j_max.max_sent_time 
ORDER BY messageTime DESC
) AS p LEFT JOIN OTHER_TABLE ot on p.id = ot.id")
fun getMyData(myId:Int): LiveData<List<ResultModel>>
```